# Why Do I have to implement Dispose from IDisposable, Why not just a simple method to release...?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Why Do I have to implement Dispose from IDisposable, What if I just implement any method in my class that releases the unmanaged resource?

People I talk to pretend to know the reason just telling me I have to do so.

Honestly, I think this is the kind of question too-obvious-to-ask-although-Idon't-know between some developers

Comment: A simple method, you mean one perhaps like Dispose?

Comment: of course, why should I implement Dispose from IDisposable?

Comment: I thought Dispose was a simple method to release unmanaged resources - It just has a common name so the framework knows about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> People I talk to pretend to know the reason just telling me I have too.

Because it establishes a common interface (method) of releasing native resources.  When you properly implement `IDisposable` I can now:

1. Work with your type through the `IDisposable` interface if I need to.
2. Wrap the creation of your type in a `using` statement instead of writing `try/finally` all over the place.
3. Use automated tools to detect instances in which I have failed to call `Dispose()` on an instance of your class (i.e., instances of classes which implement `IDisposable`).
4. Rely on the runtime to call your finalizer (which will call `Dispose()` as long as you are implementing your class correctly) if I make the mistake of not calling `Dispose()` directly.  Not saying that you should do this as it makes resource management non-deterministic, but it is a nice just in case feature.

You don't *have to* implement `IDisposable`, you just should when your type is managing native resoruces (resources which cannot be managed by the runtime).

Comment: +1. @ThePoet - implementing `IDisposable` on an object that manages some non-trivial/non-managed resource is convention - and as result most people who read the code would know what to expect. Ed S' answer lists benefits you get when writing it (via support in C#/framework), but I'd say it is as important to let readers know expected behavior in common way. Note that [coding by convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) is very common in other frameworks too - ASP.Net MVC is an example in .NEt land.

Comment: Implementing `IDisposable` doesn't give one any assurances regarding the finalizer that one wouldn't have without it.  While there are some costs associated with having finalizers run, and calling `Dispose` to perform cleanup so the finalizer doesn't have to is generally a performance win, there are a few classes in the Framework (e.g. `Threading.Thread` and `WeakReference`) which do not implement `IDisposable` but have finalizers anyway.

Comment: @supercat: I don't see your point.  A class which properly implements `IDisposable` will call `Dispose()` from the finalizer if it has not been called already. That is obviously a good thing. It's not magic, it's just one last chance to clean up after yourself.

Comment: you mean, the Garbage collector finalizer calls the Dispose from the class implementing IDisposable?

Comment: @EdS.: The only classes which should use finalizers for cleanup are those whose sole purpose is to manage a single unmanaged resource (a group of things that are always acquired or released as a unit might be considered a single resource).  If a more complex class would need an unmanaged resource, that resource should be encapsulated within an instance of a possibly-private class whose purpose is to manage its lifetime; if the lifetime-managing class has a finalizer, the outer class won't need one.

Comment: @supercat: And your point is...?  We're talking about managing native resources here, I'm not sure what you're going on about.  Who is talking about the number of logical resources being managed?

Comment: @EdS.: My point is that the vast majority of classes which implement `IDisposable` should not have cleanup finalizers; I thus disagree with your statement "A class which properly implements `IDisposable` will call `Dispose()` from the finalizer...."  That may have been the thinking once upon a time, but since then it has since become apparent that it's better to encapsulate unmanaged resources in objects whose purpose is to manage their lifetimes.  While types requiring cleanup should generally implement `IDisposable`, there are a few classes in the Framework that use finalizers alone.

Comment: @supercat: I never once said to rely on finalizers.  I went as far to say that you definitely should *not*.  However, I'd like for you to offer an example of a type which implements IDisposable which should *not* call Dispose() (if needed) from the finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

The `IDisposable` interface is unique in that its presence actually says less about a class than its absence.  If a class implements `IDisposable`, the class indicates that it *might* have asked some outside entity (which could be any kind of entity, anywhere in the universe) to do something on its behalf until further notice, to the possible detriment of other prospective users, and it *might* consequently have a responsibility to ensure that the outside entity gets notified when its services are no longer needed.  For example, an object which encapsulates an input stream might have asked the underlying operating system for exclusive access to a file [which might possibly be on a different computer]; until either the object tells the OS that it is done with the file, or the application hosting the object terminates, nobody else anywhere in the universe will be able to access that file.  The object thus has a responsibility to notify the OS when the file is no longer needed.  Note that a consumer of an input stream wouldn't really care whether the stream has actually asked any outside entity to do anything on its behalf.  Instead, as soon as the consumer of a stream knows it won't be needed any more, the consumer calls `Dispose` on the stream, which can then perform whatever action, *if any*, is necessary to ensure that all entities who are still acting on its behalf (again, if any) are notified that they can stop doing so.

Note that `IDisposable` doesn't say that a class will ever actually ask any outside entities to do anything on its behalf, nor that it actually has any cleanup responsibilities, nor that any actual harm would be caused by abandoning an instance without calling `Dispose`.  If a class does *not* implement `IDisposable`, however, that provides a very strong indication that instances of the class have *not* assumed any responsibility to ensure outside resources get cleaned up.  At minimum, it provides a strong indication that the object may be safely abandoned without leaving any necessary cleanup actions undone [some types like `WeakReference` require cleanup but do not implement `IDisposable`, instead relying upon finalization]

Consequently, I would posit that a good reason for classes to implement `IDisposable` rather than using some other cleanup method is to avoid giving the false impression that cleanup isn't really required.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that your release function will be called under all circumstance, no matter what happens, exception, application crash etc etc. then I will say, you don't have to implement IDisposable interface.

but the truth is, If you are writing a class , or a component, you can't predict how your customer is going to use it.  they might forget to call your release function. which will result your resource not release.

Implement IDisposable interface is a good practice